# Squid proxy configuration for allowing few youtube URLs

Tags: squid

I want to full block the youtube.com website from accessing via squid. After blocking the youtube I want to allow few 100 URLs of youtube to be accessed via squid. That only educational videos will be allowed. My squid installation is working fine. But I got stuck at the url_regex part. I can't allow few URLs of youtube. Either youtube is blocked or youtube is fully opened. Here is my sqid configuration file.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl allowed_videos dstdomain "/etc/squid/allowed_videos"
acl blocked_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/blocked_sites"
http_access allow allowed_videos
http_access deny blocked_sites !allowed_videos

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 512 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Content of the allowed videos file is give below
    .youtube.com/watch\?v=6tO_isJQfCY

Content of the blocked websites file is given below
    .youtube.com

**Please help so I can partially allow youtube videos for accessing via squid**

Answer (score -1):

- You could not use Squid Proxy as a Firewall for content filtering.
- *SquidGuard* is Good too who wants to filters lots of URLS and Sites with a DB files.
- *url_regex* is not good to you because Youtube channels are contain with unknown characters

So you should use a some app or make developing code with Python to Check the entire Content of Sites to make it allow or deny for your clients.

> But in this case I suggest you manually allow the URL ( like as White list ).

This is sample code that you want :

- First save the URLS in the file : "/etc/squid/mywhitelist.txt"
- Then you should allow just this file for your clients like this code :

> ```
> acl youtube_access src "/etc/squid/mywhitelist.txt"
> http_access allow youtube_access
> http_access deny all
> ```